# How to add a new device to a team provisioning profile

Tags: ios

I have a new device for our app to be tested on, so I added it to the provisioning portal.

There are currently two development provisioning profiles - however the provisioning portal will not let me edit the team provisioning profile in order to add the new device. 
 - But I'm sure this something I've done before as I've previously added new devices as they arrived to enable testing with them.

How can I add the new device if the profile isn't editable? (

(The limit has not been reached, there's only several devices in the portal in total).

Comment: If the team provisioning profile was created by Xcode it's possibly being managed by it via the organizer?

Comment: Yes in the portal it says its managed by Xcode - but I can't see any way how to edit it in Xcode?

Comment: FYI - as of XC 7.0+ see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724957/xcode-7-how-do-you-refresh-provisioning-profiles/32725552#32725552 in order to refresh your team provisioning profiles

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to edit it, click Refresh in Xcode Organizer to make it generate a new one for you automatically.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick thanks. If I wasn't here and another team member (an admin) wanted to add the new device would they just follow the same steps? (Would they have to download the profile first, then click update?)

Comment: There is no need to download Team Provisioning Profile, clicking Refresh is all they need to do.

Comment: I do not have the option "Automatic Device Provisioning" how shall I do it now?

Comment: This checkbox is conspicuously missing from XCode 4.5 ... and since then I've not been able to add devices to my team profile.

Comment: hitting refresh in organizer did not work for me. I ended up clicking on my device (in organizer) and clicking "Add to Portal". I can now use my device for testing.

Comment: The checkbox is no longer present in Xcode, so this answer is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 19):

**For Xcode 5 :**

From the Xcode menu select **preferences>>Accounts**, Select your Apple ID then select Details...

You will get a popup with your Signing Identities and Provisioning Profiles.

Click the Refresh button in the bottom left and the iOS Team Provisioning Profiles get re-generated and downloaded.

Comment: As of Xcode 6.2, you follow this steps to update provisions from library, and you must select the right current team provision up-to-dated one.

Answer (score 10):

> For new **XCode 5 & Xcode 6**

### Adding Device UDID to Provisioning Profile on developer.apple.com

Login to iOS dev center and go to Device section under 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles'

Add new Device using UDID

[image]

---

### Update Provisioning profile with newly added Device

Once you have added the device and need to update your developer provision profile

[image]

Select newly added device in provisioning profile and click Generate

[image]

---

### Update XCode with Updated Provisioning Profile

Finally goto XCode --> Preferences --> Accounts --> ViewDetails -->Refresh -->Done

[image]

That's All Go for Clean and Build now.
Cheers!!

Comment: That's exactly what I used to do, but for some reason the "Edit" button is no longer enabled! Have any idea why?

Comment: @Michael's answer below refers to a SO answer that holds the solution

Comment: @RDC will it effect the already prepared builds or apps in device ?

Answer (score 1):

On XCode 7 the answers here are inapplicable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32725552/1449799 should work (delete the profiles in xcode, and tell it to download them again), BUT unlike the instructions at the link, for XCode `Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)`, you (or at least I) cannot select multiple profiles at once.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Organizer window in Xcode. With your device plugged in to the computer, select your device in the Organizer.

In the area detailing your device's specs, click the button titled "Use for Development". You may need to log in to your Apple Developer profile. Once that's done, your device should be listed as part of the provisioning profile and have the profile installed.

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to plugin the device? A couple of weeks ago one of the director's wanted to install the app on his phone and I managed to add his device id to the various profiles within obtaining it physically. So now I'm confused how I successfully did that a couple of weeks ago but now can't seemingly add this new device.