# The  Automatic Device Provisioning options have gone since upgrading to Xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm making a release for the first time since upgrading to Xcode 4.3.1.

While having a look to see if my profiles were up to date I also noticed that automatically updating device provisioning is no longer displayed (i.e. where it should appear in this screen shot doesn't appear for me [How to add a new device to a team provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506600/how-to-add-a-new-device-to-a-team-provisioning-profile)) but it used to there before I upgraded.

Is this something that has been removed with 4.3.1? If not, why is it no longer appearing for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing it either.  I'm having lots of troubles with code signing and ad hoc distribution, so I'm trying to follow Apple's (recently updated!) step by step instructions. However, they don't appear to match the options I have in XCode.  It appears that "automatic device provisioning" has been silently removed as an option, or my Organizer install is corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

xCode 4.3 now has the Refresh link on the far right, and there is no longer a checkbox for "Automatic Device Provisioning," at least that I can find.

Just clicking the Refresh link on the right is all that's needed to update the app's provisioning profile from developer.apple.com.