# Why can't I see provisionning profiles in my XCode 5 Organizer?

Tags: xcode

If look at the picture here [How to add a new device to a team provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506600/how-to-add-a-new-device-to-a-team-provisioning-profile)

I can see provisionning profiles whereas in my xcode 5 organizer I can only devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provisioning Profiles are no longer in the Organizer.  You access them in the Xcode menu under:
Xcode-->Preferences-->Accounts-->Apple IDs-->View Details.