# xcode 7.2 distribution certificate not showing in build settings

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Xcode 7.2. I installed the distribution certificate. It is available in keychain but it's not showing in build settings.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh your profile list in Xcode.
Otherwise delete the profile from **Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> View Details** and click **Download all** button.

Refer this [Refresh Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724957/xcode-7-how-do-you-refresh-provisioning-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

1st change the provisioning profile for release, then change in Code Signing Identity .If this won't solve your problem then quit Xcode and restart the system may solve your purpose .