# The team provision profile invalid

Tags: ios, xcode

On the iPhone Provisioning Portal, the team provisioning profiles with the specific ID is invalid.

As I did some research on net and it said I should click on the Xcode preference, then click the view details about the account, and then click the refresh button on the bottom right corner but I could not find it.

Comment: well, I mean i could not find the refresh button.

Comment: and the team provision profile is managed by Xcode. Should I delete it? Because the app was already available at the app store, I don't know what would happen if I just delete it.

Comment: You can delete any provisioning profile it wont affect anything on the app which is already on the app store.

Comment: Great!.  What about the certification? If I delete the push notification, would that cause a problem?  Because I search On web, Someone had this problems,too.  and they delete all the certification,and then the team provision profile is valid.      Tks for your replying.

Comment: See my answer i have explained abt all your querries at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you can create,edit or delete provisioning profile (developer,distribution) or certificates which wont effect the apps already live (on app-store). But it will effect the apps that you are using in your current project for testing in Device.

You can Delete all provisioning profiles and certificates. But you have to create again for testing your app in to device as well as upload new app on app-store from iTunes connect.

Apple provide Very nice and clear documentation please read bellow link for more clear

[Provisioning and Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)

**Push Notification**

The push certificate cannot be renewed. You have to create a new one.

The push notification certificate is not part of the application build. Therefore for push to continue working you only have to create a new certificate and deploy the p12 file (or whatever other format you are using) at your server. You don't have to submit a new version of your app.

**Regarding refreshing the accounts** and provisioning profiles, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724957/xcode-7-how-do-you-refresh-provisioning-profiles) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729193/refresh-devices-in-team-provisioning-profile-managed-by-xcode-7).

Comment: Thanks.it does help me a lot.