# If provisioning profile is set to "automatic" is it necessary to update?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I need to renew the provisioning profile for one of my apps within the next few days. In the Xcode project however it's set to "automatic", does that mean Apple will do it automatically? What happens if I don't renew it?

The app is currently in the app store by the way, not sure if that matters.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need to worry about the app on app store, it will be fine.

Second, you have to download the new provisioning file in XCode for the new version. If you don't download the new provisioning file even if you set it to 'Automatic', there will be an error when you build the project.
(If you don't know how to refresh the provisioning files, see this: [Xcode 7 how do you refresh provisioning profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724957/xcode-7-how-do-you-refresh-provisioning-profiles))

Third, I would suggest you to choose the specific provisioning file instead of setting it to 'Automatic' because based on my experiences, xCode will select the wrong provisioning file for you sometimes.

Fourth, you have to make sure the build that you submit to app store is using 'Distribution' provisioning file in 'Release' mode. If you set it to 'Automatic', there will be a chance that it selects the wrong one for you.

Comment: Okay, I made a new one in the developer center and downloaded it. However, when I select it in Xcode I see a list of a few provisioning profiles but it's not among them. Do I have to add it to Keychain? How do I get it in the project? Thanks again!

Comment: For new provisioning profiles, you don't need to download it from the apple member centre. After you create a new provisioning file, just simply go to xcode -> preferences... -> accounts -> select your account -> click "Vide Details" and Download the new provisioning file -> set the new one in your Build Settings

Comment: If that is not ok, I think its because of the new xcode bug. To fix it, go to xcode -> preferences... -> accounts -> select your account -> click "Vide Details" and right click the provisioning file -> view in finder -> delete it manually and redownload it again -> renew it in project build settings